# How can i get X value from selenium class Point

Tags: selenium, webdriver

`point = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view`

I have this instruction which returns an object of class Point. If i print it out

```
print(point)
```

I get the next result

```
{'x': 555, 'y': 389}
```

The question is: How can i get the X or Y value from this point, i tried `point.getX()` and it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`point` is a *dictionary*, get the values by the key:

```
point["x"]
point["y"]
```

Comment: I can accept answer only afte about 10 minutes, and i was waiting,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation , your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: I can't even upvote you answer, so don't blame me, thank you!

Comment: @SavinVadim nono, don't worry about that, most importantly the issue is resolved. Thanks!